# What do Hindu scriptures say about the relationship between religion and politics?

Tags: dharma, scripture

It is believed that in ancient times, the Rishis and the Gurus used to guide the kings regarding how to run the kingdom.

Nowadays, we see many countries have a separation of the government and the religion (at-least officially) e.g. in the US, there is a separation of Church and State (although, it is said that the Church has a lot of control on the politics)

What do Hindu scriptures say on the role of religion in politics?

Comment: This would not be in the Sruti texts, there may be something in Manu's laws as it addresses the duties of the different castes, including the duties of kings. On a separate note, Nehru attended Gita classes every week in Delhi for many years given by a austere sadhu and Indra Gandhi used to consult with a well known saint.

Comment: raja dharma is supposed to protect veda dharma. separating religion and politics is like separating father and mother, and telling child (citizens) to follow one or other as they wish. just plain stupidity in the name of being 'progressive and secular'. btw, in case of conflict between the two, mother is supposed to obey father, same for children - listen to father (religion).